# Htaccess rewrite url not working

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have created a .htaccess file to rewrite url. But when i opened the url which should be rewrited by the htaccess the url was not changed. Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule seller/username/(.*)/ seller.php?username=$1    
RewriteRule seller/username/(.*) seller.php?username=$1
```

Please help me out as i am beginner to htaccess. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which URL do you want to change?

Comment: seller.php?username={any username}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+seller/\.php\?username=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /seller/username/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^seller/username/(.+)/?$ seller.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```